# Fastest way to run a function millions of times in Go (without running one after another)

Tags: go, optimization, concurrency

There's a function which takes 2 seconds to finish. It needs to be executed 3,000,000 times. Executing in normal succession like below will take more than 2 months:

```
for i := 0; i < 3000000; i++ {
   myFunc()   //takes 2s to finish
}
```

Naturally I think of executing them in concurrent Go routines:

```
for i := 0; i < 3000000; i++ {
   go myFunc()
}
```

But I guess the system will eventually crash before finishing due to out-of-memory since the number of concurrent goroutines is too large to handle. Then how can I ensure the success of all 3 million executions within the shortest time?

Comment: Use a worker pool sized to fit in memory.